# How to import from subpackage (without exposing) when building using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, setup.py, python-packaging

I am packaging a personal Python project and uploading it to pypi. It has the following structure:

```
root
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── subpackage
│       ├── bar.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── test.py
```

Now, `foo.py` has a function called `public_function` that depends on `bar.py:bar_function` , so I am structuring my code as:

```py
# package/foo.py
from package.subpackage import bar_function

def public_function():
    return bar_function()
```

```py
# package/subpackage/__init__.py
from .bar import bar_function
```

My goal is to let people call `public_function` while hiding all its dependencies like this:

```py
import package
package.bar_function()
```

So `package/__init__.py` looks like:

```py
from .bar import bar_function
```

This is working correctly when importing from `test.py`, but when building using setuptools, things start getting weird.

After checking these similar questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528178/right-way-to-set-python-package-with-sub-packages), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244869/python-package-can-not-import-subpackages-when-installed-with-setup-py) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460509/personal-pypi-package-cant-import-subpackages)) these are the two approaches I have tried, but don't work as I want:

### Approach 1

As I don't want to expose `subpackage`, I tried:

```py
# package/setup.py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='package',
    packages=['package']
)
```

But when I do `import package` (after uploading to pypi and running `pip install package`), I get the following error:

```
File /venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/package/foo.py:1
----> 1 from package.subpackage import bar_function
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar_function' from 'package.subpackage' (unknown location)
```

(I also tried with a relative import `from .subpackage ...` but didn't work)

### Approach 2

As it looked like the subpackages are not making it to the build, I tried:

```py
# package/setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='package',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Which doesn't yield the error anymore, but now I end up exposing everything else (i.e I can do `import foo` and `import subpackage`) which I don't want.

**What should be the right way to set up my package? Is it even possible to achieve what I want in Python?**